# "through Wednesday" vs. "until Wednesday"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What's the difference, if any, between:

- for the week of Thursday, January 5 *through* Wednesday, January 11.
- for the week of Thursday, January 5 *until* Wednesday, January 11.

?

Context:

[image]

Comment: It's the same week, obviously! The difference is just that ***through*** is more readily understood as ***inclusive*** (***until*** isn't always inclusive).

Comment: Through used in this way sounds like US usage to me (in Aus). I would expect until, and the reference to the week would make it clear Wednesday was part of the time period.

Comment: Same in the UK. We don't use through in this way either. Definitely US usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Brit, I consider the use of 'through' in this way to be entirely US usage. Brits, & from comments Australians, don't use 'through', they always use 'until'.

However, this is one of those occasions where the US usage may have a better distinction than the British.

'Until' can be prone to misinterpretation.

> Sale: Everything half price until Monday, [when it will be full price again.]

vs

> Sale: Everything half price until Monday. [On Tuesday prices will revert.]

No matter how many times you see the British usage of 'until' there is always this potential for misinterpretation. It *tends* to be inclusive, but it is not compulsory.

'Through' as the US uses it, appears to *always* be inclusive.
In the particular image of the magazine as presented, there is obvious correlation, leaving no room for uncertainty.
It would be extremely unusual for a TV/radio guide to only cover six days. It would mean the magazine would have a constantly-changing publication day, cycling round every seven weeks. This is so improbable as to be immediately dismissible.